# 'ImageConverter' can't convert a Bitmap to a byte array. gets error

Tags: .net, vb.net, bitmap

Error is:
"'ImageConverter' is unable to convert 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'System.Byte'."

```
dim YZ_2D_blobmap( 150 * 100 * 3 ) as byte 
dim heatmap_PictureBox_Bitmap   as Bitmap

' . . .heatmap_PictureBox_Bitmap loaded with 150 x 100 bitmap

   YZ_2D_blobmap = Bitmap_to_Bytes( heatmap_PictureBox_Bitmap ) <<<<<<< error
    bytes_to_file( YZ_2D_blobmap, YZ_2D_BLOBMAP_BLB_PATHNAME )

        Function Bitmap_to_Bytes(  img as Bitmap ) as byte()
            dim bytes_ImageConverter as ImageConverter = New ImageConverter()
            return bytes_ImageConverter.ConvertTo( img, GetType( byte ))
         end function

         Sub bytes_to_file( byte_buffer, pathname )
            system.io.file.writeAllBytes( pathname, byte_buffer  )
         End Sub
```

Comment: How do you suppose this "converting" should happen, though? The normal way to "convert" an image object to a byte array is simply to _save_ it, _as a specific image file type_, to a byte stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling the `ImageConverter` to convert the `Bitmap` to a `Byte` rather than to a `Byte` array.  This:

```
return bytes_ImageConverter.ConvertTo( img, GetType( byte ))
```

should be this:

```
Return bytes_ImageConverter.ConvertTo(img, GetType(Byte()))
```

The error message even tells you that:

> 'ImageConverter' is unable to convert 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to
>   'System.Byte'.

Nothing there about arrays.